# The initializer parameter of reduce() on the sum of elements of an iterable

Tags: python-3.x

A query regarding this code:

```
from functools import reduce

def sum_even(it):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y if not y % 2 else x, it,0)
    
print(sum_even([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Why not adding the third parameter of **reduce()** adds the first odd element of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't pass an initial element explicitly, then the first two elements of the input become the arguments to the first call to the reducer, so `x` would be `1` and `y` would be `2`. Since your test only excludes odd `y`s, not `x`s, the `x` gets preserved, and all future `x`s are sums based on that initial `1`. Using `0` as an explicit initial value means only `0` and (later) the accumulated total of that `0` and other even numbers is ever passed as `x`, so an odd number is never passed as `x`.

Note that this is kind of a silly way to do this. It's much simpler to build this operation from parts, using one tool to filter to even, and another to sum the surviving elements from the filtering operation. For example:

```
def sum_even(it):
    return sum(x for x in it if not x % 2)
```

is shorter, clearer, and (likely) faster than the `reduce` you wrote.